# Getting current context from a GCM push notification in android

Tags: android

I am trying to display either a MaterialDialog or toast depending on the message received with the push notification. The problem I'm running into however is that the context passed in the WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) method, is not the the current context of the application. I get a bad window token error when I create a MaterialDialog with it. Does anyone know of a way to get the currently displayed activity's context from the WakefulBroadcastReciever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Christian answer , use this to send an intent when you get push message

```
Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then in your activity listen to this event by

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
```

where mMessageReceiver is a receiver instance where you need to implement onReceive message. See this gist

https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277

Answer (score 2):

If your activity is open, your BroadcastReceiver can send a (internal) broadcast message. Your activity has to register for this Broadcast-Type before (in onResume()) and deregister in onPause(). Then your BroadcastReceiver can execute something with the context of your Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is there a place I can see a good example of this implemented? I'm fairly new to android and have not worked much with BroadcastReceivers yet.

Comment: well, there are tons of tutorials and examples on Google about BroadcastReceiver, prashant added one for you